# RESTIFY not serving static files from subdirs

Tags: node.js, restify

I´m trying to serve static files with restify using following code.

```
app.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname + '/public',
    default: 'index.html'
}));
```

Calling GET / or GET /index.html works as expected. 
Calling any file in a subdirectory of public does not work.
For example calling GET /css/style.css leads to a 404.
The file exists but is not being served.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, works fine for me:

```
app.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: 'public',
    default: 'index.html'
 }));
```